# Is there a tool on Centos to send command output over udp?

Tags: linux, centos

I want to send output of `watch cat file.txt` to a udp port. Is there something already for it?

Comment: "_I want to send output of `watch cat file.txt` [somewhere]..._" I'm fairly sure you can't usefully send the output from `watch` anywhere. It's a tool intended for a real-time terminal session

Comment: Yeah I converted to a loop with cat and sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [netcat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)

For example you can send a message to UDP port 514 by piping it through nc:

```sh
echo "They are taking the hobbits .." | nc -w1 -u 192.168.1.1 514
```